# Closed caption track not working in all browsers

Tags: browser, closed-captions

I was testing a basic track html page from my desktop, and it seems that that the closed captioning works in Firefox and IE, but not Edge or Chrome. Edge shows the CC button and that it's running, but doesn't display any text, while Chrome doesn't even show CC button for me. From a website, they all work except Edge again. Ideas?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>CC Track Test</title>
</head> 
<body> 

<video controls src="movie.mp4">
  <track default kind="subtitles" label="caption" srclang="en" src="entrack.vtt" />
Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>

</body> 
</html>
```

**VTT:**

```
WEBVTT

0
00:00:02.000 --> 00:00:14.000
This is a test caption.

1
00:00:18.700 --> 00:00:28.500
And this is a second test caption.
```

Comment: 1) In Chrome or Chromium, can you see a "button" that looks either like a hamburger menu or three stacked dots? That's where I find CC in Chromium. 2) If the VTT file contains captions (i.e. for the deaf and hard of hearing), is there a specific reason why you set `kind` to "subtitles"? 3) According to [API Mirror](https://apimirror.com/browser_support_tables/webvtt), WebVTT *should* work in Edge, but you probably already knew that.